# Amazon MQ - Does the private IP change after a reboot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mq

I'm using the Amazon MQ managed service and have a question as to how MQ behaves on a reboot.

Will the private IP of the broker change or is it static?

I'm using Amazon MQ inside of a VPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using a single instance broker it will most likely stay the same. I couldn't find a direct documentation reference for this, but Amazon MQ broker nodes are managed EC2 instances. An EC2 instance by default retains the **private IP** inside a VPC over its lifecycle.

The problem is that you don't control the lifecycle of the instance. If the instance is broken beyond repair, Amazon MQ may set up a new instance for you, which will get a different private IP address inside the VPC, but that should be rare. After a simple reboot that would be very unlikely.

If you're using an active/standby cluster what I said concerning the IPs of the individual nodes should still be true, but the whoever the active node is may change.

If you need a hard guarantee that the IP addresses don't change, you can set up a private Network Load Balancer in front of your cluster. From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/network-load-balancers.html) (emphasis mine):

> When you create an internal load balancer, you can optionally specify one private IP address per subnet. If you do not specify an IP address from the subnet, Elastic Load Balancing chooses one for you. **These private IP addresses provide your load balancer with static IP addresses that will not change during the life of the load balancer.** You cannot change these private IP addresses after you create the load balancer.

Comment: Thanks Maurice , we are using NLB and configure private IP on target group so in production enviornment we should never expect IP's to be changed of active or stand-by brokers.

Comment: Okay, should work. The point in [Jack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66429664/6485881) is also valid. I didn't mention this, but in a perfect world the IP address of the broker shouldn't matter, so if you can get away with using security groups and DNS, please do :-)

Comment: Thanks @Maurice , agree with Jack's comment but in this scenario we have R53 in front of NLB which can be configured only on IP or instanceid &  for AWS MQ we have IP only available

Answer (score 1):

For most services in AWS you want to use the DNS name or CNAME to a service instead of any IP address unless there's a static IP address attached to it.

Comment: True, unfortunately the real world sometimes forces us to make compromises we aren't happy about :D